# Task running few seconds after the call

Tags: c#, task

I have a service that receive messages and sends them to an instance 
every message i receive i'm sending it to new Task so the operation of process the message will be async

```
public void ReceiveMessage(string Message) {
      Logger.Logger.Log($"Receive Message {Message} in METHOD method");  
      //see in the log time stamp 12:13:51.000
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Logger.Logger.Log($"Receive Message  {Message} in TASK method"); 
                    //see in the log time stamp 112:13:53.000

                    processMessage(Message);
                });
}

private void processMessage(string message) {
     //do some processing job
}
```

there are a lot of messages received in the service from different clients , each message is send to different instance , the `ReceiveMessage` and `processMessage` are methods per **instance**
So there are 2 seconds delay between calling the method and starting the task - does any one know why this could happens and how to avoid it?

I thought C# is able to manage it's own thread pools...

Comment: Although I can't explain why it's taking 2 seconds (unless this is only the first time), you have to understand that you are asking for a task to run 'in the future' but you have no guarantees when your task will run.  When there is a spare thread in the pool, your task will start, but if there are already 100 (the actual number depends on many things) tasks running there won't be any left to run your task (until some other task finishes).

Comment: As per how to avoid: roll your own thread pool. Of course this brings complexity and if you have already overloaded your system with tasks things can get worse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited number of Task that can run concurrently, check the property of `Task.Factory.Scheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel`

> The default scheduler for the Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework thread pool, which is represented by the ThreadPool class, to queue and execute work. The thread pool uses the information that is provided by the Task type to efficiently support the fine-grained parallelism (short-lived units of work) that parallel tasks and queries often represent.

However the `ThreadPool` pool size depends on several factors:

> There is one thread pool per process. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by using the SetMaxThreads method. Each thread uses the default stack size and runs at the default priority.

TheadPool - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Comment: HI - do you have an example?